# How to modify an already constructed schema

Tags: meteor, simple-schema

I'm using a third party package that defines a schema like this:

```
People.schema = new SimpleSchema({
  firstName: {
    type: String,
    optional: false
  }
  //Many other fields defined...
});
```

I would like to modify it to have `optional: true` for the first name without changing the source code for the third party package.

I could use `People.schema.pick` to get a schema with all of the fields except the `firstName`, and then combine this with another schema with `firstName` as optional. But this method would require listing all of the fields in the schema in the `pick` function, which is tedious.

Is there a better way of accomplishing this?

Comment: Or you could just reverse engineer the schema object and poke "true" into `firstName.optional`

Comment: Thanks @MichelFloyd, I used that in my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can edit the object simple schema creates just like any other object:
`People.schema._schema.firstName.optional = true`.

To override the field.

Comment: Just a thought - you'll probably have to do this both client and server side.